# JQuery Mascara de Moeda em HTML (não-input)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mask

Olá. Estou atrás de uma máscara de moeda feito em jquery, mas que se aplique direto em uma tag span de html, com uma classe específica. O que mais tenho encontrados em minhas buscas são as máscaras de input para formulários, que não é o caso. Acabei então ficando um pouco confuso, pois meu conhecimento de JS não é muito.

Então exemplificando uma **HTML**

```
    <li>
    <span class="mylabel">Valor do Aluguel:</span>
    <span class="myvalue">25000000</span>
    </li>
```

No exemplo o script transformaria esse tipo de resultado 25000000 em -> 25.0000,00
Ou seja, forçar o formato padrão de moeda daqui do Brasil em um campo escolhido.

Logicamente seguindo o mesmo padrão para outros tipos de valores:
60050 -> 600,50
110000 -> 1.100,00
250035085 -> 2.500.350,85
etc.

Possível? Como faria?

Agradeço antecipadamente.

Comment: [MaskMOney](https://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/) é parecido o uso do maskedinput [exemplos](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Currency-Input-Filed-Mask-Plugin-maskmoney/) usando mask money

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isso através de [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

```js
$(".myvalue").text(parseInt($(".myvalue").text()).toLocaleString('pt-br', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'BRL',
 
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <span class="mylabel">Valor do Aluguel:</span>
  <span class="myvalue">25000000</span>
</li>
```

Comment: Olá, muito obrigado pela contribuição. Acho que quase lá, notei a peculiaridade de que nesse caso os números finais sempre são zerados. Sendo assim como exemplo: 250035085 -> 2.500.350,00.

Comment: @LecoSantos para remover as casas decimais use como opção minimumFractionDigits: 0. Caso tenha mais dúvidas consulte a documentação na sessão Syntax https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString